# Jhipster second time CRUD

Tags: crud, jhipster

Is there a way to Jhipster to automatically generate CRUD when generating an entity a second time ?

For instance, I missed to add a field in an entity and replay "yo entity...".

I modified the .json configuration file as described in the doc but when I checked the page, the changes didn't appear.

Do you met the same issue ?

Thanks for your help, JM

Comment: If you're only adding a field, I'd recommend doing it in your entity and manually adding it in your view.

Comment: Thanks Matt but I really would like to replay the entity/CRUD generation.
I'll post the solution here if I find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is I remove all generated code (except .jhipster/.json) and run yo jhipster:entity  again. When yo jhipster:entity  has run, it outputs all the created files. I save that list in a text file for the next time I want to change the entity. This way I can remove all generated files easily. I know it's not ideal but it works for me.